# How can I account for assumed X and Y errors when using findfit?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I'm using very noisy biological data, and I need to assume, when doing linear regression, that there are errors in both `X` and `Y`. To my understanding normal regression only assumes errors in `Y`. Is there a way to specify error values for `X` and `Y` in *Mathematica*, and take that into account when finding a linear relationship between the two?